# Trying to scrape image urls but not able to get it using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapinghub

I am scraping this link : https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/all-cards/?sourcecode=A0000FCRAA&cpid=100370494&dsparms=dc_pcrid_408453063287_kword_american%20express%20credit%20card_match_e&gclid=Cj0KCQiApY6BBhCsARIsAOI_GjaRsrXTdkvQeJWvKzFy_9BhDeBe2L2N668733FSHTHm96wrPGxkv7YaAl6qEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

and get image urls

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


AMEXurl = ['https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/all-cards/?sourcecode=A0000FCRAA&cpid=100370494&dsparms=dc_pcrid_408453063287_kword_american%20express%20credit%20card_match_e&gclid=Cj0KCQiApY6BBhCsARIsAOI_GjaRsrXTdkvQeJWvKzFy_9BhDeBe2L2N668733FSHTHm96wrPGxkv7YaAl6qEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds']
identity = ['filmstrip_container']

html_1 = urlopen(AMEXurl[0])
soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(html_1,'lxml')
address = soup_1.find('div',attrs={"class" : identity[0]})

for x in address.find_all('div', class_ = 'filmstrip-imgContainer'):
    print(x.find('div').get('img'))
```

but i am getting output as the following :

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

The follwing is the image of the html code from where I am trying to get the image urls :

[image: html code from where image urls are being fetched]

This is the section of page from where I'd like to get the urls

[image: image urls]

I'd like to get to know if there are any changes to be made in the code so that I get all the image urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are dynamically loaded from a script tag. You can easily regex them from the .text of the response. The regex below specifically matches the 7 images you say you want to retrieve and show in the picture.

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/all-cards/?sourcecode=A0000FCRAA&cpid=100370494&dsparms=dc_pcrid_408453063287_kword_american%20express%20credit%20card_match_e&gclid=Cj0KCQiApY6BBhCsARIsAOI_GjaRsrXTdkvQeJWvKzFy_9BhDeBe2L2N668733FSHTHm96wrPGxkv7YaAl6qEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds').text
p = re.compile(r'imgurl":"(.*?)"')
links = p.findall(r)
print(links)
```

---

**Regex explanation:**

[image]

---

Were you to decide to go with the more expensive selenium you could match with

```
links = [i['src'] for i in driver.find_all_elements_with_css_selector('.filmstrip-imgContainer img')]
```

Comment: I'd be glad if you could help me in getting the Apply Now as well as Learn More urls as well if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests
import re

AMEXurl = ['https://www.americanexpress.com/in/credit-cards/all-cards/?sourcecode=A0000FCRAA&cpid=100370494&dsparms=dc_pcrid_408453063287_kword_american%20express%20credit%20card_match_e&gclid=Cj0KCQiApY6BBhCsARIsAOI_GjaRsrXTdkvQeJWvKzFy_9BhDeBe2L2N668733FSHTHm96wrPGxkv7YaAl6qEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds']
identity = ['filmstrip_container']

r = requests.get(AMEXurl[0])

html_1 = urlopen(AMEXurl[0])

soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
```

### Extracting All Images

```
images = soup_1.find_all('img', src=True)

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
```

### all image tags that display png files.

```
platinum_card_image=soup_1.find('img', src=re.compile('Platinum_Card\.png$'))
print(platinum_card_image.get('src'))
```

### all image tags that display svg files.

```
platinum_card_image=soup_1.find_all('img', src=re.compile('\.svg$'))

for img in platinum_card_image:
    print(img.get('src'))
```

### Edit

```
images_7 = soup_1.select('script')[8].string.split('__REDUX_STATE__ = ')
data = images_7[1]

for d in json.loads(data)["modelData"]['componentFeaturedCards']['cards']:
    print(d['imgurl'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code, but unfortunately I am not able to get all the image urls of all the 7 cards.